# how to modify related object's data whilie creating a new object in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I'm trying to do something pretty simple.
my models.py is as below:

```
from django.db import models

class DiskDrive(models.Model):
    deviceId = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    freeSpace = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.deviceId


class StoragePool(models.Model):
    poolId = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
    size = models.BigIntegerField()
    drive = models.ForeignKey(DiskDrive, related_name='pools')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.poolId
```

I haven't added anything to views.py and urls.py yet. 
I'm able to create objects of both the classes.
Whenever I create an object of StoragePool class, I want to reduce the value of 'freeSpace' attribute of the related DiskDrive object by the 'size' of 'StoragePool' object. How should I do this? Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect job for a post_save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StoragePool)
def update_drive_space(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.drive.freeSpace = F('freeSpace') - instance.size
        instance.drive.save(update_fields=['freeSpace'])
```

See [Django signals documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) for more info about how signals work. In a nutshell this method will be called each time you create or update a `StoragePool` object.

Few notes:

- I am using [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) to reference current database `size` value instead of blindly saving whatever we have on Django side (this will ensure correct value when multiple clients will create new `StoragePool` objects)
- It is likely that you want to adjust `freeSpace` attribute also when `size` is updated - not just on `StoragePool` creation. To make that happen just delete `if created` check and it will be run on every `StoragePool.save()`

Comment: It's working.... thank you pajton. Just a small edit(for those who are new to django like me): paste the above code in models.py and import following:                                               from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db.models import F

Comment: Glad I could help! I tend to omit imports out in my answers to leave some fun for the OP ;-)